# How to alert under input text with conditions?

Tags: javascript, php, validation, input, alert

[Please look the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npKYP.png)

[image]

want to divided the alert. So when value is empty or null, the alert is **nama pengguna must inputed**. And if value is less then 5, the alert is **min 5 characters**.

For the style is only like it (red text, under input text). I mean not use javascript alert.

This is my code:

```js
function checkLength() {
 var textbox = document.getElementById("username");
 if(textbox.value.length <= 5) {
  alert("min 5 characters");
 }
 else if(textbox.value.length == 0){
  alert("nama pengguna must inputed")
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group required2">
 <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Nama Pengguna</label>
 <div class="input-icon">
   <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  <input id="username" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" pattern=".{5,}" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Nama Pengguna" name="username" onchange="checkLength()" required title="nama pengguna must inputed (min 5 characters)">
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: call the checkLength() function on keydown or keyup

Comment: sorry, i've edit it

Comment: Are you asking for an alternative to `alert` or do you already have that?

Comment: @BachchaSingh **Invalid format** when value less then 5

Comment: @ujang7654321ujang7654321 check my updated answer, let me know if still you are facing issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `p tag` and append those `errors` as suggested i.e. characters length should be less then `5`, as below, I have even made few correction in conditions.

```js
var textbox = document.getElementById("username");
var pr = document.createElement("p");
function nm(){
 if(textbox.value.length >= 1 && textbox.value.length <= 5){
  pr.textContent = "min 5 characters";
  document.body.appendChild(pr);
  }
  else if(textbox.value.length === 0){
  pr.textContent = "nama pengguna must inputed";
  document.body.appendChild(pr);  
  }
}
textbox.addEventListener("blur",nm);
```

```css
p{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group required2">
  <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Nama Pengguna</label>
  <div class="input-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>

    <input id="username" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" pattern=".{5,}" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Nama Pengguna" name="username" required title="nama pengguna must inputed (min 5 characters)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your message accordingly, you will be battling against HTML5 validation, but that won’t be too big a problem.

What you need to do is to check the value when the data has changed.

Put the following into your stattup code:

```
document.querySelector('input#username').onchange=function() {
    checkLength();
}
```

By startup code, I mean whatever you use to start your script. Tuypically it is something like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoad',init,false);
function init() {

}
```

or, for older browsers,

```
window.onload=init;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want convert alert into simple text message then follow the code below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group required2">
        <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Nama Pengguna</label>
        <div class="input-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>

            <input id="username" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" pattern=".{5,}" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Nama Pengguna" name="username" required title="nama pengguna must inputed (min 5 characters)" />
<span class="username_error" class="error"></span>
</div>  
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    function checkLength(){
        var textbox = document.getElementById("username");
        if(textbox.value.length <= 5){
            document.getElementById('username_error').innerHTML = "min 5 characters";
        }
        else(textbox.value.length == 0){
            document.getElementById('username_error').innerHTML = "nama pengguna must inputed";
        }
    }
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
.error{
  color:"red";
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group required2">
  <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Nama Pengguna</label>
  <div class="input-icon"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <input id="username" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Nama Pengguna" name="username" required title="nama pengguna must inputed (min 5 characters)" onKeyUp="checkLength()">
    <br>
    <span style="color:#A42022" id="error"></span> </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
function checkLength() {
    var textbox = document.getElementById("username");
    if(textbox.value.length == 0){
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "nama pengguna must inputed";
    } else if(textbox.value.length < 5) {
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "min 5 characters";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";    
    }

}
</script>
```